# Specman e subtyping: How to refer to FALSE value of conditional field in when/extend subtyping?

Tags: specman, e

I have a unit `my_unit` with a boolean field `my_bool`. I need to add a specific logic to `my_unit` when `my_bool == FALSE`. Is it possible?

```
unit my_unit {
    my_bool : bool;

    when my_bool {
        // Works fine, I can add logic to my_unit
    };

    when not my_bool {
         // This causes compilation error!!!
         // Here I need to add another logic 
    };
};
```

Is there a way to do it? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler seems to be treating `when my_bool` as `when TRUE'my_bool`. If you want to write code for the `when` the variable is `FALSE`, you can write:

```
unit my_unit {
    // ...

    when FALSE'my_bool {
        // ...
    };
};
```